# Slow MySql Server Performance - What and How to check?

Tags: mysql, performance

*start:disclaimer*

I'm not a MySql Server DBA; I know mostly of MSSQL - which is why I need your help.

*end:disclaimer*

I've been asked to check why the MySql server engine is performing poorly - I have not seen nor held the databases involved and would like to know where to start.

Where do I start?

What questions should I be asking those who have access to MySql - I don't even know if they are using phpmyadmin or some other tool.

Essentially:

- What items should I ask for and how would I respond to each piece they give?

What are the key items to ask for when the issue is in the performance of the database?

in MSSQL I can check `sp_who2` for existing connections to see if anything is blocking, what is the counterpart in mysql?
* do not have to be specific as there can be many kinds of results for each item but would like to help get the ball rolling since it is affecting users - apparently they set up the mysql engine without having a dba on-board.

Comment: Have you checked the usual ressource issues - CPU full, RAM full / not used, IO overloading? The 101 stuffyou would start with on a sql server?

Comment: Haven't had a chance to - I just want to be prepared once i come in so that everything keeps moving - it is possible the people on-site checked already and with both app and db servers with high-specs (company splurged) i would like to focus on what happens if the hardware is not the problem

Comment: Out of esxperience - start there. I have seen "high end servers" with one SCSI hard disc (that they must have pulled out of some ebay auction) that had multi second response times... I would validate the IO side. It also will help - too much IO can point to missing indices if the numbers are just totally ridiculous.

Comment: Try [MySQL creates temporary tables on disk. How do I stop it?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/53201) and [A description of how temporary tables are created and managed in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259275/mysql-tmp-table-size-max-heap-table-size).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Log slow queries- If your system has a ton of queries, it gets tougher to find out which queries are slowing your system. MySQL provides a tool to log slow queries for further analysis
  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html
- EXPLAIN Extended command shows details about your queries when your have no idea what is happening http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-extended.html
- To speed up your queries use Index - A good practice is add index by seeing which fields are in the WHERE clause add index for them.
  Also if you are retrieving all fields from a table, the query gets slower by fetching all data from disk. In SELECT query you should specify which fields you need to bring instead to bring them all with *
- Make use of Query Cache http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-configuration.html
- Make sure that your MySQL server configuration file options are optimized according to your hardware
  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-files.html
- Make sure that you are using optimized data types while creating a table structure 
  For example "Comments" fields has size of 256 characters, reply it to MYSQL with a field with type VARCHAR(256) instead of using TEXT. The query will be much faster.

Procedure_Analyse() can help you in finding optimal data types:

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/03/23/procedure-analyse/

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/procedure-analyse.html

- There are open source tools from Percona - http://www.percona.com/software/percona-toolkit which can be helpful for MySQL DBA's and specially those who are new to MySQL these tools will provide good assistance to them.