# MariaDB writes more the 30GB/day temp data

Tags: mariadb, docker

I´ve a Synology NAS where  I´m running a Nextcloud in a Docker Container and a MariaDB in an other Docker Container. On a day the the NAS and also the Nextcloud doesn´t do anything, on my SSD are over 30GBs written.
So I´ve looking for a while and saw with *iotp*, that every time when the Nextcloud cron job is running, the MariaDB writes with over 20MB/s to my SSD.

I tried to prevent it by using an ramdisk like here written: [Why does MySQL produce so many temporary MYD files?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30505/why-does-mysql-produce-so-many-temporary-myd-files/30635#30635)

For this I created the MariaDB Docker Container with

```
docker container run -d \
--mount type=tmpfs,destination=/tmp,tmpfs-size=1g,tmpfs-mode=1777 \
....
```

but when the Nextcloud cron job is running, I still see that the Mariadb writes with over 20MB/s to my SSD :(

In the Container it looks fine:

```
df -h
Filesystem         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs              1.0G   13M 1012M   2% /tmp
```

with a script I´ve found witch uses *inotifywait* I see hat during the Nextcloud cron job a “/tmp//#sql-temptable-1-575-0.MAI” is created.

I´ve also looked with

```
touch test
=> run the cron job
find / -newer test | grep -v "^/sys/" | grep -v "^/proc/"
```

if other things where wirtten, but it doen´t seems so:

```
/dev/pts/3
/dev/pts/ptmx
find: ‘/proc/1470/task/1470/fd/6’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/proc/1470/task/1470/fdinfo/6’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/proc/1470/fd/5’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/proc/1470/fdinfo/5’: No such file or directory
/tmp
/var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0
```

Does anyone has an idea why the ramdisk not working or I can see what is written by the MariaDB and prevent it?

Comment: Does no one have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Its for the reasons mention in the link, there are a significant number of queries requiring a temporary table to resolve the query.

To find the queries set:

- [long_query_time=0.2](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#long_query_time) (called [log_slow_query_time](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#log_slow_query_time) in 10.11+)
- [slow_query_log=1](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#slow_query_log)
- [log_queries_not_using_indexes=1](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#log_queries_not_using_indexes)
- [min_examined_row_limit=1000](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#min_examined_row_limit) ([log_slow_min_examined_row_limit](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#log_slow_min_examined_row_limit) in 10.11+)

[log_slow_query_file](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#log_slow_query_file) contains the log file name to examine after uptime for all the slow queries and queries not sufficiently indexed (other criteria may apply too) to avoid temporary table usage.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer,
I know that some queries are written temporarily to disk, I can't change that because they come from Nextcloud.
Therefore I tried to move "the disk" where the temporary data is written to the memory. (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53201/mysql-creates-temporary-tables-on-disk-how-do-i-stop-it).
Unfortunately it does not work.So I am looking for an idea what / where is written from the database. My database has less then100 MB but 30 GB are written/day... that sounds strange especially if the internal queries (as I hope) end up on a ramdisk

Comment: Maybe with the right information you can advise Nextcloud of the problem queries so they can fix them. Temporary files are created with O_TMPFILE (see man 2 open) so will not appear on the filesystem and I don't know if inotify sees them. Start container with `--cap-add CAP_SYS_PTRACE` and you can `strace -p 1` after MariaDB is installed.

Comment: Thanks for the idea with strace, even if it somehow makes no sense for :/ The output of `strace -t -f -p 1 -e write,openat,close` and `iotop` do not fit together. 
Strace says that it writes to my ramdisk `openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/#sql-temptable-1-6-3.MAI")....`, but iotop says at the same time that MariaDB would write at 25MB/s. <br/>
df -h
`Filesystem         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on`
`tmpfs              1.0G   13M 1012M   2% /tmp`

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting I have not managed line breaks

Comment: The slowlog should show you the "worst" queries; let's focus on one or two of them.  We may be able to go back to the instructions you gave to Nextcloud and change things that avoid the need for temp tables.  Or we may be able to add an composite index to the table.